# Angular passing date object to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass a date object to directive via attribute. but the date is parsed to ISO string and i have no way to parse it back to date object.

What is the right and simplest way to do it?

Here is my code:

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div myDir date={{date}}></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

directive:

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    template: '',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      console.log('attrs.date: ', attrs.date;);
      var d = new Date(d);
      console.log('date: ', d);
    }
  };
});
```

The output is: 
attrs.date:  **"2015-11-16T07:05:53.159Z"**
date:  **Invalid Date**

I don't want to use the way of get the parameter on the scope with '='.
Is there other way to send date to directive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are getting value from attribute and then again you are converting that value from string to `date`, which is why your date is becoming `invalid`.

Instead of passing value through attribute, I'd suggest you to pass that value from isolated scope of directive, which will pass the object value without need of any conversion.

**Markup**

```
<div my-dir my-date="date"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    template: '',
    scope: {
       myDate : '=' //mapped with `my-date` attribute on directive element.
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      console.log('date: ', scope.myDate );
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to:

```
<div my-dir date="date"></div>
</div>
```

my-dir instead of myDir because angular performs normalisation on hyphen separated name and converts it to camel case.

Also, since you have isolate scope(scope: {}) for your directive, you don't require interpolate expressions inside the directive attributes.

Lastly, change scope in directive to:

```
scope: {
    date: '='
}
```

And use scope.date in your link function.